# Null value getting interpreted as blank space in Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file with data :

```
 A   B        C    D            E        F
"1"|"6A-7A"|"MFF" ||     "KEY"        |"Y"
"2"|"n/a"  | ""   |"n/a" | "INVENTORY"|"Y"
```

where the cell value of 1st row in D column is *null*,

When I try to read it using Pandas:

```
df =  pd.read_csv('test.csv', keep_default_na=False, skip_blank_lines=True)
```

I get the output:

```
A   B        C    D            E        F
1  6A-7A    MFF               KEY       Y
2  n/a           n/a       INVENTORY    Y
```

where the *Null* value is printed as blank space.

The desired output is:

```
A   B        C    D            E        F
1  6A-7A    MFF  NaN          KEY       Y
2  n/a           n/a       INVENTORY    Y
```

How to achieve this?

P.S - Attached a screenshot of the data for reference

[image]

Comment: Can you copy raw data in the csv file to reproduce?

Comment: Attached a screenshot for your reference

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.